# If DateTime is immutable, why does the following work?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I thought I understood what Immutable meant, however I don't understand why the following compiles and works:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Copy and paste the next part a few times

```
dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt);
Console.ReadLine();
```

As expected, it runs, and when I press enter, it then displays the next time... I thought this was not possible and I would need to create a new object. Why is this allowed/working? Or, is the book I am working from wrong and DateTime is not immutable (However I have read this on several sources)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `DateTime` object itself is immutable, but **not the reference dt**. **dt** is allowed to change which `DateTime` object it points to. The immutability refers to the fact we can't change the variables inside a `DateTime` object.

For example, we can't go

```
dt.Day = 3;
```

**dt** itself is just a reference variable that points towards a `DateTime` object. By its definition, it's allowed to *vary*.

As [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst) mentioned, though, [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) and [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) are probably closer to what you're thinking, where you can't change the value of a variable.

---

Side note: [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a [Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031.aspx), and therefore, a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=vs.80).aspx), and I'm being misleading by calling `dt` a 'reference.' However, I think it still holds true that `dt` is still just a variable 'pointing' at an immutable object, and the variable itself is still mutable. Thanks to [dan04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287586/dan04) for pointing that out.

Comment: Perhaps mention `readonly` or `const` (although these modifiers only apply to members).

Comment: Makes perfect sense - Both you and BoltClock have good answers so in 8 minutes, I will flip a coin!

Comment: @Wil BoltClock was here way before me, so he probably deserves the accept :-)

Comment: It isn't about speed!!! And yours went in to more detail first (both upvoted) - I just wish I could accept both, so a coin is fairest!

Comment: Isn't `DateTime` a `struct` rather than a `class`?

Comment: @dan04 True. I should probably add that so my answer isn't misleading

Comment: @ZachL, the clarification at the bottom is helpful, but it would be better to reword your answer so that it doesn't need a clarification to begin with, perhaps along the lines of ", but not what object is stored in _variable_ `dt`"

Answer (score 21):

You're simply telling the variable `dt` to refer to a different instance of `DateTime`. Under the hood, the `DateTime.Now` property generates a new `DateTime` instance every time you access it.

Comment: ahhh - so I am misunderstanding the meaning... My object is changeable, the source of .now/the time/date isn't (I think I understand, I just can't explain...)

Comment: @Wil: You can change the variable, but not what the variable is pointing to. As an analogy, you can stick a label on something, take the label out and stick it on something else, but you don't change the thing that the label is attached to, only where the label is.

Answer (score 5):

The Now property is something like:

```
 DateTime Now {
     get {
         // Get the OS time
         return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec...)
     }
 }
```

(technically false, the Now calls internally the UtcNow that calls the OS :-), but you get the idea).

The DateTime.Now is a factory for DateTime :-)

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime#methods).

Read the description of all those methods. It always says "Returns a new DateTime...".  It does not change the current DateTime object, thus it is immutable.

Variable reference is a different thing.  Think of it just as a pointer to the actual immutable DateTime object that can be changed to point a different one.

Answer (score 0):

If an instance of a non-trivial structure type is stored in a writable storage location (non-`readonly` field, local variable, array slot, etc.), all of its fields will be mutable.  If an instance is stored in a non-writable storage location (a `readonly` field, a compiler-generated temporary value, etc.), then none of its fields will be mutable.  The concept of an "immutable structure type" is a misnomer, since the statement:

```
myStruct1 = myStruct2; // Assume variables are of the same structure type
```

will, if `myStruct1` is writable, replace all public and private fields of `myStruct1` with the corresponding fields of `myStruct2`; if `myStruct1` isn't writable, the statement will generate a compile-time error.  *The code for the structure gets no say in the matter, and won't even be notified that the assignment as taken place*.

Although `DateTime` provides no means by which an existing `DateTime` instance can be modified *except by whole-structure assignment*, it can do nothing to prevent code from overwriting the fields of one instance with the contents of another, as happens with `dateTimeVariable = DateTime.Now;`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple. DateTime is not immutable. It is a struct. And I don't know how it's possible to have an immutable struct.

If you do this:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
d1 = d2;
```

Then, the struct d1 will be overwritten with d2's values.

(A DateTime really only has one value. If you run a decompiler it is a private field called "ticks" I believe.)

There is no reference stuff going on, or anything else funky.