# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

The data suppose to be inserted without any error as long as the inserted data in right format but what make me wondering is that data can not be inserted even though data in right format! what is wrong here ?

table:

```
create table announ(
    id int not null primary key,
    comName varchar(200) not null,
    sName varchar(100)  not null,
    annDate datetime2(7) not null,
    fYearEnd datetime2(7)  null,
    quarterr int  null, 
    QFREDate datetime2(7) null,
    figure varchar(50)  null,
    fName varchar(50)  null,
    contentType varchar(200) null,
    data varbinary(MAX) 
)
```

Code:

```
 string query = "insert into announ (comName,sName, annDate, fYearEnd, quarterr, QFREDate, figure, fName, contentType, Data) values (@comName,@sName,@annDate, @fYearEnd,@quarterr, @QFREDate,@figure,@fName, @contentType, @Data)";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comName", txtcname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", txtsname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@annDate", txtannDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fYearEnd", txtfye.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quarterr", txtq.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QFREDate", txtqfre.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@figure", txtf.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you give samples of the format you are using for your dates?

Comment: for example this format 2/2/2015

Comment: where to parse into date time?

Comment: Use 'CDate' Function for Example                                                                                                           'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@annDate", cdate(txtannDate.Text));'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this changes where the text can be parsed into datetime and it works

```
string query = "insert into announ (comName,sName, annDate, fYearEnd, quarterr, QFREDate, figure, fName, contentType, Data) values (@comName,@sName,@annDate, @fYearEnd,@quarterr, @QFREDate,@figure,@fName, @contentType, @Data)";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comName", txtcname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", txtsname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@annDate", DateTime.Parse(txtannDate.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fYearEnd", DateTime.Parse(txtfye.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quarterr", txtq.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QFREDate", DateTime.Parse(txtqfre.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@figure", txtf.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert it to change the actual DateTime? Remember that DateTime is immutable, you can not actually change DateTime. You will have to reference the value of DateTime and then make a modified version of it.

[DateTime Immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052406/if-datetime-is-immutable-why-does-the-following-work)