# Date range is not working properly in for loop

Tags: c#, date, for-loop

I am using a for loop with date range in C#.

```
for (var date = fromDate;date <= toDate; date.Value.AddMonths(1))
```

However, I found out that the date value is not added in the looping. Is that the AddMonths is not appropriate in the for loop? How should I add the months in the for loop?

Comment: for (var date = fromDate;date <= toDate; date = date.Value.AddMonths(1))

Comment: `DateTime.AddMonths` does not add months to the date it was called upon (check gnud's answer for the cause), but does return a new `DateTime` with the month added.

Answer (score 7):

[`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) values in c# are *immutable*. That is, after they are created, they *can't be changed*.

What you can do, is assign a new value to the `date` variable.

```
for (var date = fromDate.Value; date <= toDate; date = date.AddMonths(1))
{
    // do something with date
}
```

Comment: I would suggest checking this for further info of the inmutable https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052426/2265446